# Rendering Angular2 components by class selector

Tags: angular, angular2-template

My question is simple, but believe me, I've been trying to wrap my head around it for hours now.

There's a component that's to be instantiated via a class selector.

```
@Component({
  selector: '.mycomponent',
  template: '<h1>hello!</h1>'
})
export class MyComponent{}
```

Let's say the parent Component looks like this:

```
@Component({
  ...
  template:
      `
        <div class="mycomponent"></div> <!-- rendered -->
        <div [class]="'mycomponent'"></div> <!-- not rendered -->
      `
})
export class ParentComponent{}
```

Why is it that the second version is never rendered? How would I make it render? Is this a change detection issue or is it just not supposed to work this way?
I've played around with the change detection strategy, which didn't have any effect. Also I've come across `DynamicComponentLoader`. My hopes are that I can get around using it.

Is there any way to load components dynamically via non-element selectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not supposed to work. Components and directives are only applied to statically added tags, attributes and classes.

If you want to dynamically add/remove components and directives use [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html) or `createComponent()` of [ViewContainerRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewContainerRef-class.html)

Comment: Is this the same for something like: `<div class="template-class-{{templateID}}></div>"` accompanied with: `selector: '.template-class-1'`?

Comment: Yes exactly, because dynamic HTML like your example  doesn't work for selectors. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Answer (score -1):

Why it's not work is because when you use [class],it's meaning that "class" is an attr not assigning "mycomponent" class to div.